# How can my script prompt me for the number of users I need to create?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have this script on a Linux machine:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Creating a user file using while loop"
Name=" "
Surname=" "

for ((i=1;i<6;i++)); do
    ((a=((i-1)%5)+1))

    echo "USER: $i"
    echo "_________________"
    echo "Enter first name"
    read Name
    echo "Enter surname"
    read Surname
    echo "Your name is $Name"
    echo "Your surname is $Surname"
done
```

How can I modify it so that it prompts me for the number of users to create?

Comment: Your script is already using a loop in which you read data from the user, interactively. What stops you from reading in the number of iterations (before the loop) and then using that number instead of the hard-coded `6`?

Comment: @Kusalananda What i want to do is, my script to prompt me how many users i want to create. if i press 2 then only 2 users to be created, if i press 6 the only 6 users to be created

Comment: You already know how to ask for a name and surname. Asking for a number of users is quite similar.

Comment: @choroba if i use read -p "How many users do you want to create?" User, then i press 2 it only loops for 5 users not for 2 that i pressed

Comment: Then show us how your did that please. That is the code we need to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in the number of users to create at the top of the script, and then use that number in your loop.

This is a suggestion for a variation of your script that you could additionally give the number of users to on the command line. If you don't give a number on the command line, it will ask interactively for that number.  No input validation is done.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

nusers=$1
if [[ -z $nusers ]]; then
    read -p 'Number of users to add: ' nusers
fi

for (( i = 1; i <= nusers; ++i )); do
    read -p "User $i first name:  " name1
    read -p "User $i second name: " name2

    printf 'Hello %s %s\n' "$name1" "$name2"
done
```

Testing:

```
$ ./script.sh
Number of users to add: 2
User 1 first name:  Apple
User 1 second name: Wonder
Hello Apple Wonder
User 2 first name:  Mini
User 2 second name: Uncle
Hello Mini Uncle
```

```
$ ./script.sh 2
User 1 first name:  Moped
User 1 second name: Runner
Hello Moped Runner
User 2 first name:  Tentative
User 2 second name: Luck
Hello Tentative Luck
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Creating a user file using while loop"
Name=" "
Surname=" "
echo -n "Enter the number of users to create: "
read no_of_users
for ((i=1;i<=no_of_users;i++)); do
        echo "_________________"
        echo "USER: $i"
        echo -n "Enter first name: "
        read Name
        echo -n "Enter surname: "
        read Surname
        echo "Your name is: $Name"
        echo "Your surname is: $Surname"
done
```